# css positioning issue - happening on some pages but not others

Tags: css

I've noticed that on some product pages of my site (but not all) I'm getting a strange issue where one of the product images appears in the row below the one it's meant to.

So on some pages the 'People who bought this also purchased...' images, on the last line one of the products drops down a line and is obviously out of place.
http://tinyurl.com/cs6d3q5

but most other pages are fine!
http://tinyurl.com/clwq3dz

I can't figure out whats the problem. As far as I can see they should both act the same way. Can anyone enlighten me and also tell me how they debugged it? I use Firebug and developer tools on FF but they don't seem as useful as they once did

thanks

here's the code used to create it:

```
if($also_purchased_products->RecordCount() > 0) {
    echo '<div style="clear:both"></div>';
    echo '<div class="sideboxHeading">People who bought this also purchased...</div>       <div class="ProdInfoDotSpacer"></div>';
    while (!$also_purchased_products->EOF) {
        $also_purchased_products->fields['products_name'] = zen_get_products_name($also_purchased_products->fields['products_id']);
        echo '<div class="alsoPurchasedWrapper">';
        echo '<a href="' . zen_href_link(zen_get_info_page($also_purchased_products->fields['products_id']), 'products_id=' . $also_purchased_products->fields['products_id']) . '">' . zen_image(DIR_WS_IMAGES . $also_purchased_products->fields['products_image'], $also_purchased_products->fields['products_name'], SMALL_IMAGE_WIDTH, SMALL_IMAGE_HEIGHT) . '</a><br />';
        echo '<a href="' . zen_href_link(zen_get_info_page($also_purchased_products->fields['products_id']), 'products_id=' . $also_purchased_products->fields['products_id']) . '">' . $also_purchased_products->fields['products_name'] . '</a>';
    echo '</div>';
    $also_purchased_products->MoveNext();   
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its because

```
 <a href="http://www.traditionalirishgifts.com/black-sage-guinness-harp-knit-scarf">Black/Sage Guinness harp knit </a>
```

here `Black/Sage Guinness harp knit scarf` is long try sorting it

[image]

Comment: Hi, bugger, that was easy. I applied a height and overflow hidden and that seems to have sorted it. Can I ask what you used to figure things out? Thanks for the help by the way!

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears when the previous item text link is more than one line long. You can truncate it, as NullPointer says, or set a height on `.alsoPurchasedWrapper`:

```
.alsoPurchasedWrapper {
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 5px 0px 10px 20px;
  height: 170px;
}
```

Comment: Hi, bugger, that was easy. I applied a height and overflow hidden and that seems to have sorted it. Can I ask what you used to figure things out? Thanks for the help by the way!

Comment: Well, this is actually a very common problem, when floated elements behave like this (Like skipping the position where they're supposed to be) is usually a height problem. Also, every jumpy item had an item with a two-line link on top-left of it :P Anyway, this is an usual problem, next time you see it you'll catch it fast :D